# android - how to inflate a map fragment in an already inflated layout?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

i am creating a Table Layout in my an activity, adding dynamically table rows in a loop.
What i want to achieve, is to add a Google map fragment in each dynamically created Table row.

This is my Table row Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_rowitem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp">
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/inflated_row_relative"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_poi_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/orange"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:text="Name"
android:gravity="center"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_snapshot"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_poi_name"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/map_snapshot" />              
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_poi_address"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Address"
android:textColor="#fe8301"
android:layout_below="@+id/img_snapshot"         
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />    
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/distance_layout"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_poi_address" >      
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:src="@drawable/distance_icon" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_poi_distance"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
android:text="Distance"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
```

And this is the loop that i am creating the Table rows dynamically:

> final TableLayout tblAddLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl_menu_pois); 
>     TableRow inflateRow = (TableRow) View.inflate(Menu_pois.this, R.layout.menu_pois_rowitem, null);
>     for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
>
> ```
>   View inflate = (TableRow) View.inflate(Menu_pois.this, R.layout.menu_pois_rowitem, >tl_menu_pois);
>   RelativeLayout inflated_row_relative = (RelativeLayout) >inflate.findViewById(R.id.inflated_row_relative);
>   inflated_row_relative.setTag(i);
>   TextView poi_name = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.tv_poi_name);
>   TextView poi_address = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.tv_poi_address);
>
>   poi_name.setText("Name");
>   poi_address.setText("Address");     
>   //set tag for each TableRow
>   inflate.setTag(i);
>   //add TableRows to TableLayout
>   tblAddLayout.addView(inflate);
>   //set click listener for all TableRows
>   inflated_row_relative.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>           Object tag = v.getTag();
>           String string_tag = tag.toString();                         
>       }
>   });
> ```
>
> }

I want to display a Google map in each Table row like the image bellow (instead of the sample image, having the map):

http://goo.gl/9erYB7

Is there a way to implement this?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for adding multiple map fragment on the same View, following this example, in case someone has the same problem:

http://saadroid.blogspot.gr/2013/06/multiple-maps-in-same-view.html